# Increment specific cell number by one

Tags: google-apps-script, auto-increment

Google Spreadsheet.

I already have a script that is adding a row with a date each day using a daily trigger, I want to add a sub routine that increments a specific cell value by one. The trigger will run this script daily.

Current script:

```
function onTop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.insertRows(2);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "MM/dd/yyyy")
  ss.getRange("E2").setValue(date);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cell = ss.getRange("CellNotation");
var cellVal = parseInt(cell.getValue());
cell.setValue(cellVal + 1);
```